# Connecting to RabbitMQ container from containerized app

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I'm trying to connect to rabbitmq through my application,both of which run on containers through docker-compose.Here is relevant code from docker-compose.yml

```yaml
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    networks: 
      - mynetwork

    {service}:
        container_name: {app}-container
        image: {image}
        ports:
          - 5030:80
          
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: {path}
        environment:
                - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        networks:  
          - mynetwork
```

This is how I have rabbitmq's configured:

```cs
_factory.HostName="rabbitmq";
_factory.User="user";
_factory.Password="password";
_factory.Port=5672;
```

and it doesn't work...I get this error: `RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable`
It works if I run my app's container locally and connect to containerized rabbitmq with 127.0.0.1  .Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you run it from local system or docker container? Where that exception come from

Comment: @BatuhanAtalay both of them are running on docker containers.

Comment: Can you ping etc. ```rabbitmq``` if you attach to your application container?

Answer (score 0):

if both of your containers are in the same group (example in the picture below),
you can connect to it using its name (i.e. `https://tyk-pro-docker-demo-tyk-pump-1` in this example)

[image: docker ui example]

using `127.0.0.1` inside a container will refer to the container itself. one workaround is to use `host.docker.internal` with port number using the exposed port number.

> **This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Windows** [from docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/)